# What are those big floating things in Super Meat Boy called?

Tags: super-meat-boy

I mean those floating corpses that chase Meat Boy about in the Chapter 5: Rapture.

Comment: Hell on earth? I don't think the Super Meatboy enemies have official names.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I posed this question to [Edmund McMillen](http://edmundm.com/), one of the creators of Super Meat Boy, and he answered that these enemies are called Oobs. There is even a level in the Cotton Alley world called [Oobs' Revenge](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-cjVrRxbF-I).